# Will changing the category name affect SEO?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, seo

As you can see here
[image]

I want to just name the **products** "For Kompakt, Elscooter, Trehjulet" etc as the **parent category** is already named "Elscooter". This is mainly because I want all the **sub-categories** to be aligned perfectly horizontal with each other.

[image]

If I change the "Name" to "Kompakt" f.ex. Will this affect **SEO**? I thought just leaving the Page title for meta would be good on its own ?

Comment: Seo will affect only when you change Meta details of a category not the name and description. If you have no meta details then it will the details from original content, in that case it may affect your seo.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot affect SEO. You can change the category name.:)